# Consume REST Webservice with JSONPath

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web-services, jsonpath

I just started with RESTservice in Java. Currently I can publish my own REST service locally, but I don't know how to use it in a client. I developed the REST WebService without the JsonPath, the xml is like this:

[image]

Are there any information/documentation that can help me to use JSONPath? Is there another method I can use beside JSONPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849816/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-jsonpath

Comment: OO7: The answer in that question is not really what I am looking for, I prefer with someone that can explain it instead of only give a link

Comment: @eng i belive that you bascially want the output in both xml as well as JSON format is this correct?